# Invalid literal for int() with base 10:''

Tags: python, casting, slice

I'm trying to teach myself python and I'm trying to create a remotely accessible server for GPIO connections for my Raspberry Pi. When I make a connection, the first input I send is whatever I actually type into Putty, and then the input is ''. So I put in a check for that but I still get that message on the if int(data[0])==0: line. Any tips? Sorry if this is a newbie question.

```
def run(self):
    try:
        while True:
            ret = -1
            data = self.cs.recv(self.BUFFERSIZE)
            if data=='':
                continue
            elif int(data[0])==0:
                self.cs.send(str(GPIO_setup(data)))
            elif int(data[0])==1:
                self.cs.send(str(GPIO_output(data)))
            elif int(data[0])==2:
                self.cs.close()
    except RuntimeError:
        if self.cs:
            self.cs.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

data[0] might be ' ' or a zillion other things that aren't a number.   But to debug, try something like:

```
def run(self):
    data = None
    try:
        while True:
            ret = -1
            data = self.cs.recv(self.BUFFERSIZE)
            if data=='':
                continue
            elif int(data[0])==0:
                self.cs.send(str(GPIO_setup(data)))
            elif int(data[0])==1:
                self.cs.send(str(GPIO_output(data)))
            elif int(data[0])==2:
                self.cs.close()
    except RuntimeError:
        print "error on input of: '%s'" % data
        if self.cs:
            self.cs.close()
```

Comment: tried this and it fails with `error on input of: ` and there's a new line...so I'm guessing that data is a \n character...Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Because of you code and the error I suspect that `data` is a list. This would fail in exactly the way you observed:

```
In [2]: data = ['', 'test']

In [3]: data == ''
Out[3]: False

In [4]: data[0]
Out[4]: ''

In [5]: int(data[0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4196b6567736> in <module>()
----> 1 int(data[0])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Note that because of this definition of `data`, the original test isn't triggered while the conversion still fails.

Therefore it is better to use another test that tests `data[0]` directly;

```
data = self.cs.recv(self.BUFFERSIZE)
if len(data[0]) == 0:
    continue
```

Comment: that test fails as well...it seems len(data[0]) isn't 0 and len(data) isn't 0 but data[0] is still ''

Comment: Please add a line `print data` to your function, run it, and show us what `data` exactly is...

Comment: Try `print type(data)`, that will at least tell you _what_ it is.